# Creating new tab in Chrome when typing into address bar

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions

This is something that other browsers can do by default, or at least Firefox.  And up until recently I could accomplish the same thing with an extension called Chrome Toolbox by Google.  However, it looks like the extension is broken – lots of the most recent reviews note issues with it.

So, this brings me to my question – is there ANY other way to obtain this capability?  Another one I'd love is for items to come up in new tabs when I click on bookmarks in my bookmark bar.  I still don't understand why these basic settings haven't been offered to Chrome users...

(Just to be clear, I understand you can do this via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but I wish to be able to do it with one key rather than a key-combo.)

Comment: Really? Ctrl+T isn't fantastic enough?

Comment: Still doesn't exist, crazy.

Answer (score 11):

You can accomplish that by typing your search or your URL in the address bar and then click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> -instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>-, so you don't need to install any add-on that probably will consume more resources than you need to perform that simple thing...

By doing that, Chrome will automatically open a new tab in background with your search, or with your URL if you typed an URL...

Note: in OSX it's <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I understand that and probably should have clarified it more in the above, I guess I will add to it.  But, yes, I understand this and still think being able to just hit enter would be easier - one key vs. 2-key combos are always easier...

Answer (score 4):

I can't imagine what's wrong with pressing 2 buttons, but if you reeealy want this, you can try writing an AutoHotkey script that would do Alt+Enter when you press enter, if and only if the Chrome process is open. That should do the trick.

```
#NoEnv
#IfWinActive ahk_exe chrome.exe
Enter::
Send {LAlt down}{Enter}{LAlt up}
```

Comment: @Levi: AutoHotkey is the perfect solution for "hacks" like this. I highly suggest you have a look at this. It might look like a techy solution, but it's realy quite easy to set up.

Comment: +1, as for the bookmarks, links and any clickable pages, you can hold CTRL and click on a bookmark, link to open it on a new tab OR SHIFT to open it in a new window ;)

Answer (score 1):

I second @MegaBluejay's answer, but that answer isn't good because it will affect pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> anywhere in Chrome, not just the address box, so if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it will send <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> which has different behavior in some instances like in Google Sheets.  I'd suggest mapping a key you don't use (like <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>) to do what you want.  Also, instead of `{LAlt down}{Enter}{LAlt up}`, you can just use `!{Enter}`. Here's a working example:

```
#NoEnv
#IfWinActive ahk_exe chrome.exe
CapsLock::Send !{Enter}
#IfWinActive
```

Of if you use Caps Lock and want to use a different key that you don't use, you could use `AppsKey` if your keyboard has it.  This is the menu-looking key which brings up a right-click menu.  I've usually seen it located between the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys.

Comment: Certainly a valid concern! However, this solution is no better than just pressing Alt+Enter in the first place. :D

Comment: @DanielB The OP's requirement is they don't want to press two keys.

Comment: You’re right, I misread your suggestion. Sorry! I think the numpad enter key might be more appropriate, though. :D

Comment: you're right. I didn't think of that

Comment: Is there such a thing as a context-specific key assignment? Like, assign numpad Enter to be the Funky Enter, where its effect varies according to what's selected onscreen.

Answer (score 1):

Extensions are a blessing overall,   but I  also still cannot find one that will do  what is enabled so easily in Firefox (opening URLs in address bar in new tabs).  The proposed solution of Alt+Enter is contrary to the reasonable  goal of  increasing efficiency, and for one as myself with stiff arthritic fingers, then the less keys I use to provide content then the less typos and mistakes i make,  thus saving   lots of time  in correcting typing.

For that reason I  do have Auto Hot Key installed (remapping such keys as  Caps Lock to copy, and ESC to paste, and Num Lock to ESC, middle mouse to cut, as
NumLock::Esc
CapsLock::^c
Esc::^v
mbutton::^x  )

So I downloaded, extracted and ran the chrome_and_edge_addressbar_new_tab.ahk that cdull graciously compiled and  it works in Edge, but I much prefer Vivaldi (also Chromium-based) as it allows more customization   (esp. multiple tab rows) and so I will have to find out how to make it  work in that browser.

Answer (score -3):

After long search i found a AutoHotkey solution for this:

You find it here:

https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=87043&p=382552#p382552

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: You're right, but that AutoHotkey discussion is no simple thing. Probably christiandul should have posted this as a comment.