# How to force chrome open a new tab when I press enter on address bar without holding the alt key?

Tags: google-chrome

I found a similar question here [Creating new tab in Chrome when typing into address bar](https://superuser.com/questions/666455/creating-new-tab-in-chrome-when-typing-into-address-bar) , but all the answers suggest holding the <kbd>alt</kbd> key.

I'm always need to open a new tab at any time, so I don't like to holding any key when I press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: All browsers implement this feature in very similar ways. Enter to stay in that tab, the some combination of ctrl & alt to either open in a new tab behind or new tab in front. I don't know of any that will replace the initial enter-only behaviour.

Comment: @Tetsujin Firefox can do this by toggling the "browser.urlbar.openintab" (in about:config) to true.